# Odds of 250,000 people having the winning PowerBall ticket number.

Tags: probability

I have a question:

I understand that the odds of winning the PowerBall are about 1 in 175,000,000. Assuming that figure is approximately correct, then what are the approximate odds of 250,000 people choosing the correct winning number?

Any help will be appreciated Thanks

Comment: sometimes different people choose the same 'magic' number: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467575/should-i-put-number-combinations-like-1111111-onto-my-lottery-ticket/468258#468258

Answer (score 0):

Since ${250000\over 175000000}={1\over 700}$ the odds are approximately 1 in 700.

Comment: You are assuming that they choose distinct values.

Comment: Yes, it is an approximation. For a more accurate answer, the OP would need to specify more exactly how the quarter million tickets are chosen.

Comment: Assuming the question was meant to read (odds of someone winning the lottery), I love this answer.